# How do I pass a method to a function requiring a static lifetime parameter?

Tags: rust, lifetime

How do I pass a method to a function, considering the function takes a "handler" with a static lifetime?

*(The exact use case behind this is the creation of an [Iron](http://ironframework.io) Chain in a struct).*

Considering we have the following struct `Chain`:

```
struct Chain
{
    f: Box<dyn Fn()>
}

impl Chain
{
    fn new(handler: impl Fn() + 'static) -> Self
    {
        return Chain { f: Box::new(handler) };
    }

    fn invoke(&self)
    {
        (self.f)();
    }
}
```

When trying to create an instance of this `Chain` using a closure, while also passing a method in the closure...

```
struct MyStruct
{
    the_answer: u32
}

impl MyStruct
{
    pub fn run(&self)
    {
        let closure = || {
            println!("Closure called");
            self.printer_method(String::from("printer_method")); // <-- Problematic line
        };

        let chain = Chain::new(closure);

        chain.invoke();
    }

    fn printer_method(&self, msg: String)
    {
        // Access to self.the_answer
        println!("The answer is {}, your message is: {}", self.the_answer, msg);
    }
}
```

...the compiler gives the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
```

*I've played with the idea of declaring `MyStruct` and its members static, but being able to create multiple independent instances of the struct is a requirement (cf. multiple instances of an Iron web server).*

Here's a [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6abb25ce799c0efaa8a7787fe41b6c67).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your closure:

```
let closure = || {
    println!("Closure called");
    self.printer_method(String::from("printer_method")); // <-- here
};
```

You are capturing `&MyStruct` because of a method call. Since closures in rust are basically just structs with "call" method, this closure can't be 'static because it would outlive the reference to `MyStruct`. The solution is to get generic over this lifetime:

```
struct Chain<'a>
{
    f: Box<dyn Fn() +'a>
}

impl<'a> Chain<'a>
{
    fn new(handler: impl Fn() + 'a) -> Self
    {
        return Chain { f: Box::new(handler) };
    }

    fn invoke(&self)
    {
        (self.f)();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a great suggestion, and a simple explanation! In my specific use case with Iron (the `Chain` API belongs to Iron), I guess I'm might be stuck without solution though...